# Ansible, ssh, id_rsa.pub

Tags: ssh, ansible

Есть такая задача:
1 мастер сервер с установленным Ansible и с десяток серверов, которыми надо управлять через Ansible

у каждого из 10ки я знаю root пароль (условно ***$$2020***) и пароль SU (условно ***##9999***)

на мастер-машине я выполняюся стандартные манипуляции (на мастер-машине я всё запускаю от имени root):

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

создаются ключи

```
id_rsa id_rsa.pub
```

Enter passphras - я ввожу типа biggy

дальше я пытаюсь скопировать id_rsa.pub на все мои 10ть серверов

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@10.10.10.10
```

при копировании меня спрашивают root пароль, который я знаю. Я пытаюсь его ввести, но мне три раза ***access denied*** хотя если через putty захожу на любой из 10ти серверов с мои root паролем - всё отлично
А при копировании этот же root пароль не срабатывает.

В чем моя ошибка? Система Debian
Спасибо!

Comment: На серверах обычно `ssh root@..`  юзеры не принимаются. Или везде разрешить в настройках, или создавать другие пользователи надо. А после контакта, из них уже делать `su -`.

Comment: Разрешить **root** login : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/v2v_guide/preparation_before_the_p2v_migration-enable_root_login_over_ssh

Answer (score 0):

я понял свою основную ошибку:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@10.10.10.10
```

я использовал **root** для копирования ключа, надо было использовать пользователя под которым будет работать Ansible
правильная строка должна быть такая

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub anton@10.10.10.10
```

тогда копирование происходит корректно, а пароль используем от учётной записи **anton**

Тогда мне система сообщает, что:

```
 /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: “/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

Но я захожу на сервер и в указанной папке файла id_rsa.pub отсутствует

хотя система пишет, что ***Number of key(s) added: 1***

Спасибо!